# Symfony ghost directory ".idea"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am confused, I was working with symfony project, but out of nowhere this ".idea" directory was added to my project root directory, I have no clue what is generating it, but when I delete it keeps poping back after some interaction with my project like page request.

Also it might be worth to mention that I has following structure:

```
\.idea
    \scopes
        \scope_settings.xml
\project-name.iml (this is my project name)
\encodings.xml
\misc.xml
\modules.xml
\workspace.xml
```

and they contain something like this (scope_settings.xml) for example

```
<component name="DependencyValidationManager">
    <state>
        <option name="SKIP_IMPORT_STATEMENTS" value="false" />
    </state>
</component>
```

I searched my project for clues what may be creating this directory but only found gitignore of ".idea" directory inside vendor/common/doctrine

I would really like to find out what is this directory, and what it's purpose, and if possible how to get rid of it, for it's annoyance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are project data/metadata created and used by [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

It likely just means that you or someone has used IDEA to view or edit the code.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that I have unhanded code somewhere, I recently start using, PHPStorm, so never encountered anything like this.

Comment: You can simple remove it from your project by adding the folder to the `.gitignore`